# I'd like to ask a question to explore a topic

Tags: discussion

I'm interested in finding out if [this hack for Dungeon World (DW)](http://www.story-games.com/forums/discussion/19273/a-descriptive-damage-hack-for-dungeon-world-world-of-dungeons) works well or not.  Asking "Hey, what do you guys think about X?" is definitely not a good fit for this site.  Instead, maybe I could ask questions like:

1. Would this rule work well in DW?
2. [What repercussions would this rule have in DW?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77611/how-does-the-descriptive-damage-hack-affect-dungeon-world)
3. Are there any published works in the larger DW/etc. world that use this kind of rule?

Are any of these good questions?

Am I even going about this the right way?

Answer (score 9):

For me this is similar to the types of issue we have around questions asking about homebrew mechanics. It's very easy for those to be badly worded and/or answered, but the way to avoid both is to limit answers to those from people who have actual experience of what you are asking about.

So in this case, I think your question would work if it was of the format - 'How does this hack impact the way Dungeon World plays', along with a clear statement that only answers from people who have actually used the hack are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

Read https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/. I can't really add much to that.

As to your proposed questions:

1. Define "work well" please; as in what are you looking for the rule to accomplish. Without knowing your objective we don't know if the potential outcome of the proposed rule is a good thing for you or a bad thing for you.
2. Better, but you should focus the scope, as in repercussions for what in particular.
3. This one is a pure factual question: "I want to do X. Does anyone know of a published rule that does X?" As such this is a perfect fit for the site.

Now I know nothing about DW and the linked information is way to long for me to bother reading (there's a hint right there) but a question that may be a good fit for the site is:

> I am interested in a more descriptive damage system for DW along the lines of what is described here[link]. A summary of this system is:
>
> *5 line summary*
>
> Would anyone with experience of this or a similar modification please provide feed back on if this:
>
> 1. Makes combat more or less deadly for PCs
> 2. Is quicker or slower to run
> 3. Has knock on effects of the relative power of hackers versus spellcasters